# specifying a 30s ACL not working with Cloudfront?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Using the PHP Amazon SDK I am successfully able to set a 30 second access for a URL using the following functin:  `get_object_url($bucket, $filename, $preauth = 0, $opt = null)`

```
$s3->get_object_url($results['s3.bucket.name'], $results['s3.file.name'], '30 seconds');
```

Now, the issue with this is that it returns a fantastic URL:

```
"s3.url": "http://THECOOLEST.BUCKET.INTHEWORLD.EVER.s3.amazonaws.com/2011/04/18/image/png/8ba2d302-a441-45d4-8354-08e2b7e1a325.png?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1303162244&Signature=AWdUnHSaIBDmRcbwo2RFSUQaqBM%3D",
```

When I change the URL to the CNAME we use for cloudfront, the ACL doesn't work.  Anyone know how to `get_object_url` with the CNAME configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudfront and S3 are two different things.

You need to setup a CNAME for your S3 bucket. See the AWS docs for more info: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs

Comment: Geoff, the CNAME is already configured.  The ACL does not apply to the CNAME url ... only the default URL.  This is also a cloudfront question ... not an S3 specific question.

Comment: @sdolgy - Your question is still confusing. `get_object_url` generates a url for a file in S3 but later on you talk about a Cloudfront CNAME. CNAMES and Urls for Cloudfront and S3 are different. To generate a url for a Cloudfront file you would use `get_private_object_url` in `cloudfront.class.php`. See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonCloudFront/get_private_object_url

Comment: there you go ... that's the answer i was looking for.  cheers for following up Geoff.